# Error while displaying row when resizing browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and I came across the following error in displaying some buttons:

[image]

The HTML code is the following:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <div class="col-lg-6 text-left">
        <button class="btn btn-primary profile-button">Save</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary profile-button">Reset</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for the custom class is:

```
.profile-button {
    min-width: 125px;
}
```

The error only occurs when I am resizing the browser width. The screenshot attached is when the browser has half the width of the monitor (so 540px, given my resolution). I believe the display error starts at the 768px width value. The resolution I am currently using is 1920x1080.

I've tried wrapping the row inside a container div and also inside of a div that had both container and container-fluid classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `col-xs-6` class to both div

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6 text-left">
        <button class="btn btn-primary profile-button">Save</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6 text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary profile-button">Reset</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/25d51fja/)

## [Bootstrap Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

---

[image]

Comment: Most welcome @SSJVegito. Enjoy bootstraping. Image added for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap puts columns one under the other on smaller devices... It's likely that your columns are becoming full width and stacking, instead of staying at half the size. This is the standard behaviour.

If the buttons must remain side by side, I would recommend using your own classes and floating them, ensuring the max-width is 50%